# scrapy: spider was closed before having got something

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get names of shops from taobao.com with using scrapy. However I found the 'closing spider' shows up after 'craweled(200)' and I got nothing. 
The followings are my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from TBFXSpider.items import TbfxspiderItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class TBFXSpider(Spider):
    name = "TBFXSpider"
    start_urls = [
        "http://s.taobao.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.url == "http://s.taobao.com/":
            print "******response url:%s******" % response.url
            url = "http://s.taobao.com/search?spm=1.7274553.1997520241.3.bKiaLP&q=%E8%BF%9E%E8%A1%A3%E8%A3%99&refpid=420462_1006&source=tbsy&style=grid&tab=all&sort=sale-desc"
            yield Request(url,callback=self.parse)
        else:
            sel = Selector(response)
            items = []
            keys = sel.xpath('//*[@id="J_itemlistCont"]/div')

            for key in keys:
                item = TbfxspiderItem()
                d = keys.xapth('div[4]/div[1]/a/span[2]').extract()
                item['desc'] = [d1.encode("utf-8") for d1 in d]
                items.append(item)
                yield item
```

I doubt it might be a problem about xpath. But I checked the xpath with xpath helper and it's correct. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually about your XPath expression - *it matches nothing*.

Proof from the [shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell "http://s.taobao.com/search?spm=1.7274553.1997520241.3.bKiaLP&q=%E8%BF%9E%E8%A1%A3%E8%A3%99&refpid=420462_1006&source=tbsy&style=grid&tab=all&sort=sale-desc"
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@id="J_itemlistCont"]')
Out[1]: []
```

If you dig up a little more, you'll find out that this is due to the *asynchronous nature of the target site*. The main content of the page is formed with javascript which is executed in the browser. In other words, there is no element with `id="J_itemlistCont"` in the `response.body` that Scrapy receives.

In fact, if you'll inspect the "main" div element, you would see:

```
In [8]: response.css('#main').extract()[0]
Out[8]: u'<div id="main" class="srp-main">\n        <div class="srp-loading" style="text-align:center; margin: 100px auto 0;
...
MOFDhs5S4CADs=);"></div>\n    </div>'
```

This is basically the state of the page once the browser receives it - without a "dynamic" part. In this state, the only element inside the "main" div is that `div` element with `class="srp-loading"`, which is basically the spinning circle that you can see before the main content appears in the browser.